# How can I delete "Save as" dialog from my Xcode template?

Tags: xcode, xcode-template

I've done my custom Xcode template. It creates 2 implementation and 3 header files. 
I input only 1 name and others are chosen automatically. But when I save these files "Save as" dialog appears. When I create usual Obj-C class using Xcode template there is no such dialog. I want to remove it from my custom template also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally have found an answer.

http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/11/creating-custom-xcode-4-file-templates/

The 5th comment:

> This a pretty random find I had, but if you want the save dialog to
>   only ask WHERE to save the file and not WHAT and WHERE, you must name
>   one of the fields **productName**. Hope this saves someone the hours it
>   took me.

Comment: Thank you so much. It's really helpful to me. :)